# Remove MSMQ Queue Permissions

Tags: powershell, msmq

I want to remove all of the permissions on an MSMQ queue before we set the new permissions, this will be deployed via Octopus.
This is so that we can be sure that no legacy permissions can exist and be sure that the permissions will be the same.

```
$QueueName = "MyQueue"
$QueuePermissions = Get-MsmqQueue -Name $QueueName | Get-MsmqQueueACL
$QueueUsers = $QueuePermissions.AccountName | Get-Unique
foreach ($User in $QueueUsers)
  if ($User -like 'MyDomain*'){
    #Something like
    $QueueName | Set-MsmqQueueACL -UserName $User -Remove
  }
```

Unfortunately I need to create a CSV list of permissions for Set-MsmqQueueACL to be removed.
How can I get this?

I'm fairly new to PowerShell so anyhelp would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can pass multiple users to the `-UserName` parameter. So all you need is to create a csv with the usernames. You will find plenty examples to do this on so.

Comment: Is the CSV supposed to be input or output? IOW do you need to create a CSV listing what must be removed, or do you need to create report of the permissions that were removed (or would be removed)?

Comment: My end goal is to remove all of the permissions that exist currently.  I wasn't aware that I could pass multiple usernames.
Can I just pass the result of Get-MsmqQueueACL to remove the permissions?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, delete queues and recreate is the more reliable approach.

I assume you have a reason that requires you to not delete them. Here is an approach I think suit you best.

Using [MessageQueue.ResetPermissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.resetpermissions(v=vs.110).aspx) Method from [System.Messing.MessageQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Code example for powershell:

```
$QueueName = ".\private$\MyQueue"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Messaging
$Q = [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]($QueueName)
$Q.ResetPermissions()
```

Note: This method put queue permission back to default where only creator has full access to the queue. My powershell is using an automation account that created these queues thus it would take away fine from this point. However, in my past experience if all the queue permissions are messed, and you don't have an account that have full control of the queue, you might end up have to remove the physical queue file from storage and restart MSMQ service to clean it up. Thus I'd urge you to maintain consistence of the permission so your later operations on the queue can be performed without problem.

Comment: I can't import the System.Messaging namespace as there is a defect in .Net that limits the length of the queue name.
We are using Octopus Deploy to set the permissions at each deployment and we don't want to remove the queues and recreate them as in production this could mean that messages would be lost.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, your solution should work, just be careful preserve minimum permission for your deployment account so it can put other permissions back. Besides, [queue name longer than 64 chars slightly reduce performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706083(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: The performance reduction appears to only be for public queues, mine are all private (thankfully).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution that appears to work, as mentioned above I am no PowerShell expert but it may help someone else in the future:

```
$Queue= "MyQueueName"
#remove old permissions
$QueuePermissions = Get-MsmqQueue -Name $Queue | Get-MsmqQueueACL
$QueueUsers = $QueuePermissions.AccountName | Get-Unique
foreach ($User in $QueueUsers)
{
    Write-Output "Permissions found for user: $User"
    $tst = $QueuePermissions | where {$_.AccountName -eq $User}
    $tst = $tst | Select -ExpandProperty Right
    foreach ($Permission in $tst)    
    {
        Write-Output "Removing permissions: $Permission"
        $thisQueue | Set-MsmqQueueAcl -UserName $User -Remove $Permission | Out-Null
    }
}
```

Comment: The $thisQueue variable needs to be set:  
$thisQueue = Get-MsmqQueue -Name $QueueName
I'd advise not removing all permissions as it can render the queue unuseable for MSMQ if all permissions are removed.